# Created xlsx file delete written formula

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I create an excel file via slsxwriter and want to put there a formula. I'm doing it like this:

`sheet.write(2, 6, "=IF(AND(ISBLANK(J2); ISBLANK(K2); ISBLANK(L2)); \"PASSED\"; \"FAILED\")")`

trying also this:

`sheet.write_formula(2, 6, "=IF(AND(ISBLANK(J2); ISBLANK(K2); ISBLANK(L2)); \"PASSED\"; \"FAILED\")")`

But when I later open created xlsx file, excel want to 'repair' my file and is deleting the formula... 
(Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part)

When I was putting it by hand in excel it works great.

Anyone has an idea what is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formulas are stored in Excel in U.S. English, no matter what language you are actually using. The U.S. English separator is the comma (`,`), not semicolon (`;`).

See the section titled "Non US Excel functions and syntax" in the chapter ["Working with Formulas"](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_formulas.html) in the official documentation.